# Allowing access to Service account with gdrive when Global Policy restricts sharing externally

Tags: google-cloud-iam

Struggling to get a difinitive answer on this so would appreciate any help.

We have a Python Script that pulls data from a piece of hardware and uploads it to a Google Sheet using the drive / sheets api.

We also have a global policy in the top level OU to Restricts sharing outside of the organisation.

If you create a seperate OU in GAdmin console where external sharing is allowed and move the Account assosiated the with Gdrive / Gsheets to this OU, everything works. You share the sheet with the service account as part of the process.

This also means however the owner of the account can share other data using the account. We'd like to lock down the account , but I'm not sure it's possible as you can't whitelist service accounts, only other Gsuite domains.

There is also a point discussed about using the option to grant the service account "delegating domain-wide authority to the service account for a particular API scope (i.e. Drive) -" but from a security point of view that option that doesn't seem optimum either.

Is there any other way to achieve the access where by you can restrict sharing only with the service account and organisation accounts.

The below describes the process:

https://towardsdatascience.com/accessing-google-spreadsheet-data-using-python-90a5bc214fd2

Similar question previously.

[Whitelisting Service Account for Google Drive Document Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44827662/whitelisting-service-account-for-google-drive-document-access)